# How to add a block within twig template in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

Does anybody know how to add a search block into main-menu block via twig template in Drupal8?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSdv7.png)

I need something like that in main-menu.html.twig:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-9"> menu ....</div>
        <div class="col-md-3"> Search block should be added there</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution!
We can add a new region in **themename.info.yml**, like that:

```
regions:
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  navigation_collapsible: 'Navigation (Collapsible)'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  blog_menu: 'Blog menu'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'
```

And then call this wrapping this region in **page.html.twig** as needed.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {{ page.blog_menu }}
</div>
```

So, both blocks (menu and search) will be added inside new region via admin and wrapped.